# winforms web browser capturing form details for a login

Tags: c#, winforms, dom

I want to make a app that allows me to use a web browser component in a winforms so that a user can save the login details for a site.

Assume that the webbrowser takes a url entered by the user, they have a login page, user and password and a button

I want to store all this information and then allow the user to fire up their default browser using the stored login information.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;

        IHTMLElement activeElement = htmlDocument.activeElement;

        if (activeElement != null)
        {

           txt_password.Text = activeElement.id;
           txt_password_value.Text = (activeElement.innerText);

        }
    }
```

I can store the name of the user and password fields but cant capture the text in the current form from the method above.

I also am struggling to capture the button on the form,

Is it a good idea to have some kind of function that highlights any dom element with a red border when the mouse hovers over it (only for textboxes, buttons) so that they can right click it and store this information for their auto login?

Later I need to also work out how to launch the default browser using the stored information

Yes I have already developed a firefox plugin to do this, and chrome and IE but I really need to do it this way somehow!

Answer (score 0):

```
  IHTMLElementCollection hTMLInputElementCollection = tag.getElementsByTagName("input");

            //All input tag such as Textbox , Radiobutton , Checkbox

            foreach (HTMLInputElement elInput in hTMLInputElementCollection)
            {

                switch (elInput.id)
                {
                    case "txtusername":
                        elInput.value = "";
                        break;
                    case "txtpassword":
                        elInput.value = "";
                        break;
                    case "btnlogin":
                        elInput.click();
                        break;
                }
            }
```